# React: A non-serializable value was detected in the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, firebase-authentication, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to make a simple login/logout feature in my app using firebase auth rest API, I'm using redux to let user log in and logout, the user get registered perfectly in the firebase but when I hit `Signup` & `Login` button of the form, I'm getting this error

[image]

With redux toolkit I'm wondering what's going wrong with my `initialState` of `login` function.
Here is my code: -

```
//login-store.js
const { configureStore, createSlice } = require("@reduxjs/toolkit");

const userAuth = createSlice({
    name: "login",
    initialState: {
        token: "",
        isLoggedIn: false,
        login: (token) => {},
        logout: () => {},
    },
    reducers: {
        logginOut(state) {
            state.isLoggedIn = false;
            state.logout = () => {
                localStorage.removeItem("userLoginToken");
            };
        },
        loggingIn(state) {
            state.isLoggedIn = true;
            state.token = localStorage.getItem("userLoginToken");
            state.login = (token) => {
                return localStorage.setItem("userLoginToken", token);
            };
        },
    },
});

const authStore = configureStore({
    reducer: userAuth.reducer,
});

export const userAuthAction = userAuth.actions;

export default authStore;
```

And here I'm having my login and signup feature. Also there is one more problem, whenever I click `New User` button below the submit button, I immediately get the alert popup (written with comment below) I don't know how am I sending fetch request while switching the form...

```
//Login.js

import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { userAuthAction } from "../store/login-store";
import classes from "./pages.module.css";

export default function Login() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const emailInput = useRef();
    const passwordInput = useRef();

    const switchAuthTextHandler = () => {
        setIsLogin((prevState) => !prevState);
    };

    const loginAuthHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const enteredEmailValue = emailInput.current.value;
        const enteredPasswordValue = passwordInput.current.value;

        let authUrl;

        if (isLogin) {
            // when logging in
            authUrl =
                "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyB3Mbv38Ju8c9QedQzqX3QvufTCOXhkU0c";
        } else {
            // when signing up
            authUrl =
                "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyB3Mbv38Ju8c9QedQzqX3QvufTCOXhkU0c";
        }

        fetch(authUrl, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: enteredEmailValue,
                password: enteredPasswordValue,
                returnSecureToken: true,
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
            },
        })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    return res.json();
                } else {
                    return res.json().then((data) => {
                        // getting alert popup immediately after switching the form
                        alert(data.error.message);
                    });
                }
            })
            .then((data) => {
                dispatch(userAuthAction.loggingIn(data.idToken));
                navigate("/");
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err.message);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.loginWrapper}>
            <form onSubmit={loginAuthHandler}>
                <h4>{isLogin ? "Login" : "Signup"}</h4>
                <div className={classes.form_group}>
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" ref={emailInput} />
                </div>
                <div className={classes.form_group}>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" ref={passwordInput} />
                </div>
                <div className={classes.form_group}>
                    <button type="submit">{isLogin ? "Login" : "Signup"}</button>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.form_group}>
                    <button className={classes.newUser} onClick={switchAuthTextHandler}>
                        {isLogin ? "New User?" : "Already have account"}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Error while siging up the new user:-

[image]

Comment: The warning refers to the field "login" in your data which is a function rather than pure data. There is no reason to save this function as part of the data

Comment: but I need a function to login the user, can you tell me how can I do that if I don't use function here?

Comment: You need that function in your app, sure, but you don't need to save the function as part of the state data. After all, it never even changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should not store function references in the redux store. They are not serializable, and states should be [serializable](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware) in redux state.